# drop and create SQL Server procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to drop and create a procedure in a single script. I tried this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'P' AND name = 'Foo')
  DROP PROCEDURE Foo
  GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo
-- procedure body here
```

But I get an error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

If I remove `GO`, I get an error:

> 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch

### Update

These scripts are being executed by a Java build tool (Maven)

Comment: shouldn't that be DROP PROCEDURE foo?

Comment: is this in SSMS or are you trying to execute outside of it like in a Java client?

Comment: Would you be able to explain what higher level problem you're trying to solve with Maven and these SQL commands?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`GO` is not actually a valid term in T-SQL, it's merely the separator that the Microsoft management tools use to delimit query batches.

What are you using to run the script? If you're trying to do it in code then you'll need to split it into two statements, perhaps using a regex to split on `^GO$`

Comment: Yep, I bet this is being executed outside of SSMS.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('idhere') IS NOT NULL
   DROP PROCEDURE idhere
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE idhere
@paramsHere PARAMTYPE
AS
BEGIN
     //...code here...
END
GO
```

This is how I do it, I'm not sure what version of SQL SERVER my work uses, I believe its 2005.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better to use this syntax for the existence check:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[foo]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[foo]
GO
```

As written, if there was a foo sproc in any schema it would try to drop it. Not sure if that will make your problem go away though. If you use SSMS, there is an option to script a stored procedure as DROP and CREATE; that syntax should work.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I've found for executing a large scripts outside SSMS from a tool is to use the [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx). (iSQL pre sql 2005) This will work with any environment that allows you to run a shell command.

From the MSDN article

> The sqlcmd utility lets you enter
>   Transact-SQL statements, system
>   procedures, and script files at the
>   command prompt, in Query Editor in
>   SQLCMD mode, in a Windows script file
>   or in an operating system (Cmd.exe)
>   job step of a SQL Server Agent job.
>   This utility uses OLE DB to execute
>   Transact-SQL batches.

Answer (score 0):

Check Jon Galloway's post:  [Handling "GO" Separators in SQL Scripts - the easy way](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx)

It might have the answer you are seeking.