# CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

How must I construct sql query in java to be able execute several create statements?

Here is what I have now :

```
public static String CreateDatabaseOfflinerObjects(boolean createTables){

    String result = createTables 
            ? 
                    "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ofLastMessageTime](" +
                       "[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL," +
                       "[receiverJid] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL," +
                       "[senderJid] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL," +
                       "[lastDeliveredTime] [bigint] NULL," +
                       "[lastReadTime] [bigint] NULL," +

                       "CONSTRAINT [ofLastMessageTime_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED " +
                       "(" +
                            "[id] ASC" +
                        ")"+
                        "WITH ("+
                                "PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]"+
                              ")" + 
                        "ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] " 
            : "";

    result += 
               (
                  " ; " +

                    "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDeliveredStatus] " +

                            "@receiverJid  nvarchar(MAX), " +
                            "@senderJid  nvarchar(MAX), " +
                            "@lastDeliveredTime bigint " +
                            "AS " +
                            "BEGIN " +

                            "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +

                            "UPDATE ofLastMessageTime " +
                            "SET lastDeliveredTime = @lastDeliveredTime " +
                            "WHERE senderJid = @senderJid " +
                            "AND receiverJid = @receiverJid " +

                            "IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 "  +
                            "INSERT INTO ofLastMessageTime ( receiverJid, senderJid, lastDeliveredTime ) " +
                            "VALUES ( @receiverJid,     @senderJid , @lastDeliveredTime ) "+

                        "END" +

                   "; " +

                    "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateReadStatus] " +

                        "@receiverJid  nvarchar(MAX), " +
                        "@senderJid  nvarchar(MAX), " +
                        "@lastReadTime bigint " +
                        "AS " +
                        "BEGIN " +

                        "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +

                        "UPDATE ofLastMessageTime " +
                        "SET lastReadTime = @lastReadTime " +
                        "WHERE senderJid = @senderJid " +
                        "AND receiverJid = @receiverJid " +

                        "IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 "  +
                        "INSERT INTO ofLastMessageTime ( receiverJid, senderJid, lastReadTime ) " +
                        "VALUES ( @receiverJid,     @senderJid , @lastReadTime ) "+

                    "END" +
                     "; "
              );

    return result;
}
```

I know that there must me GO separator and I read somwhere that for java sql I can use semicolon, but this doesnt help me. Thanks.

Comment: I think this should work if you place a `GO` after the `TABLE` creation and after each `PROC` creation

Comment: `GO` isn't [TSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6443279/314291) - it's just a delimiter token - e.g. have a look at the options to change it in the drop down in [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a0e6b) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you will be able to do this in one big statement, unless your Sql connectivity tech (e.g. jdbc / CallableStatement etc) supports a delimiter token which it will implicitly use to separate out the batches (like `GO` does when using a tool like `SSMS`).

What you'll need to do is return the `DDL` for each table create separately (e.g. as a collection or array of strings), and then execute each `create` separately (e.g. in a loop, if you've used the collection approach). You won't need to create a new connection each time.

You can also wrap the sequence of DDL commands under a single ACID transaction if you need an all-or-nothing outcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to do this in a Java JDBC batch i believe,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_executebatch.htm

I believe the code would look something like:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcConn {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      Class.forName("org.apache.sqlserver.jdbc.ClientDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
      ("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test;integratedSecurity=true;");
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement
      (ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
      ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      String createTable1 = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ofLastMessageTime](" +
                   "[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL," +
                   "[receiverJid] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL," +
                   "[senderJid] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL," +
                   "[lastDeliveredTime] [bigint] NULL," +
                   "[lastReadTime] [bigint] NULL," +

                   "CONSTRAINT [ofLastMessageTime_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED " +
                   "(" +
                        "[id] ASC" +
                    ")"+
                    "WITH ("+
                            "PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]"+
                          ")" + 
                    "ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]";
      String createProc1 = "CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateDeliveredStatus] " +

                        "@receiverJid  nvarchar(MAX), " +
                        "@senderJid  nvarchar(MAX), " +
                        "@lastDeliveredTime bigint " +
                        "AS " +
                        "BEGIN " +

                        "SET NOCOUNT ON; " +

                        "UPDATE ofLastMessageTime " +
                        "SET lastDeliveredTime = @lastDeliveredTime " +
                        "WHERE senderJid = @senderJid " +
                        "AND receiverJid = @receiverJid " +

                        "IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 "  +
                        "INSERT INTO ofLastMessageTime ( receiverJid, senderJid, lastDeliveredTime ) " +
                        "VALUES ( @receiverJid,     @senderJid , @lastDeliveredTime ) "+

                    "END";
      con.setAutoCommit(false);
      stmt.addBatch(createTable1);
      stmt.addBatch(createProc1);
      stmt.executeBatch();
      con.commit();
      System.out.println("Batch executed");
      }
}
```